# Prove the metric space with the set of all real-coefficient polynomials restricted to [0,1] and the sup-metric is separable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove $(Y,d)$ is separable. To clarify, a function $~f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is an element of $Y$ if and only if $~f(x) = a_0 +\dotsc+a_{n}x^{n}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ and $a_0,\dotsc,a_n \in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R.$

Comment: @Matematleta Thank you so much! I get it!

Comment: This follows from a form of the Stone-Weierstraß theorem.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: The Stone-Weierstraß theorem would apply if the space $Y$ were of all continuous functions. However there is no need to approximate a given polynomial with another polynomial of unspecified but probably much higher degree when all you need to do is replace the real coefficients with suitable rational approximations.